# root user can access internal storage on Android?

Tags: android, root, internal, data-storage

If we keep files(pdf, epub, jpeg etc) under application's data folder on run time, is it possible to access them via root user or any other hack by somebody else?

Comment: this should be on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As root you have unrestricted access to anything on the device. Even an applications runtime data, you can retrieve anything easily. An example would be to connect your device and retrieve a file by;

```
$ adb pull /path/to/remote/file localfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Users with root rights can access anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it(internal storage) can accessible if your device is root. Then Anyone can access it.

Comment: encryption may make harder accessing the files, provided the key is kept outside the system, but it doesn't prevent  "no one can read data from that".

Comment: @bestsss - So, the meaning is even encryption is not a safe for files. right?

Comment: Just keep in mind that encryption relies on the encryption key. If you can decrypt on the device, you have to have the key on the device too. And root users can read *anything* on the device, even your key. The only thing it does is confuse amateur crackers, someone who knows only a bit what he's doing will have no problem at all.

Comment: @alextsc - these all scenario for if key is available on device. but what about it key is generated at runtime, or by user account from the net then what. All things have a both side negative/positive.

Comment: @user370305 If the key is generated at runtime, you have an algorithm for that in your apk. Which can be decompiled. Voila the cracker can build his key by reproducing that or just by calling it. If it comes from the net it will still end in the device memory. Readable. And even more, the cracker can also try to sniff the network traffic. A rooted environment is simply not trustworthy at all, all you can do is complicate things a bit. But someone who is dedicated will get it. Also keep in mind that some people crack with passion. When you provide them with a challenge, they'll favor your apps.

Comment: @alextsc - Yes, I know even more secure data also hacked, then its a simple method for hackers. But its a alternate approach to secure our data in some kind of success (if not 100% but 70-80 then also its nice).

Comment: @alextsc, there is a simple solution called memory dump, in memory the data is decrypted, so nothing really hard...

Comment: @bestsss Or that. Doesn't matter, all i wanted to point out that encryption is not safe in any case when the device is rooted. But you are right, that's also a way to get it done. :)